# gmail-apis: How to create a Gmail object with an existing access token?

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to build an offline (batch process without user interaction) Gmail app. I have an access token generated from the OAuth playground. How can I create a Gmail object from the token?

I am using Java.

Comment: Assuming your using the Java client library your probably going to have to rebuild the credentials. Its not going to work very well as when it expires in an hour its not going to be able to refresh the token for you.  Why dont you just create the access token via java?

Comment: Given this Java program runs on the server w/o user interaction, how do I get the access token?

Comment: Authenticate it once get the refresh token.   Use the refresh token to request a new access token as needed.   If its gsuite use a service account.   Go directly through the SMTP server and skip the API.   Just a few options